# Aligning 2 Tablix in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have 2 tablix one Table and one Matrix that are lined up side by side. They have relational data that I can't combine in a single query. They line up perfectly when exported and appear to line up correctly inside the original report as well. However, when it goes to load a new "Page" in Preview it loads an extra row for the matrix as compared to the table which makes the rest of the values off by 1 for each page that gets loaded.

Is there a good way to make sure they load the same number of rows on each page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 2 suggestions. You probably already tried the first, but just want to make sure it's covered.

1. Check the properties to make sure the location from the top is exactly the same. Also use a whole number, not some random fraction because it can have rounding issues.
2. Add a rectangle to the report. Drag both tables onto the rectangle. Having multiple objects inside a rectangle helps to hold them together in position when the report renders.

Comment: Adding the rectangle does indeed bind them together nicely. However, the report is rather large and previously it was broken down into loading sections in SSRS. with the implementation of the rectangle it now takes significantly longer to begin to show data because of the large dataset. Is there a good way to mitigate that by loading a "page" at a time?

Comment: Ah, that's a much broader question. There are many ways to go about tuning the efficiency. There's no specific setting to load a page at a time. I would start by looking into caching the results.

Comment: I figured that it would be impossible to recreate the default behavior. The users are just going to have to deal with a long first time load. I'll mark your answer as solution then.